# Core Data does not update inverse relationship

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

My two entities are Book and Category. A book can have many categories, and a category can have many books. The relationships are marked as the inverse of each other in the data model.

When I update the categories of a book I expected that the books of the corresponding categories would be updated automatically. In other words:

```
Book *book = [Book insertNewObjectIntoContext:context];
Category *category = [Category insertNewObjectIntoContext:context];
[book addCategories:[NSSet setWithObject:category]];
BOOL result = [category.books containsObject:book]; // Should be YES
```

Yet, I get `NO` in my app. `books` returns an empty set.

I triple-checked that the relationships are marked as inverse. What else could be at play here? Or is there something I'm missing?

Would it hurt if I set the inverse relation manually? If I do everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse relationship is not updated until the end of the run loop.  Calling it immediately after like that does not give it time to update.

If you were to do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    BOOL result = [category.books contains:book];
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result ? @"YES" : @"NO");
});
```

You would see your expected result.

### Update

It does not hurt to set the reverse manually.  When everything is working correctly it results in a waste of cycles because Core Data has to double check the relationships so you will see a performance hit.

Comment: Um. I'm still getting NO until I save the context. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: What happens if you do `NSLog(@"Books: %@", category.books)`?  What does your model look like?

Comment: Logging the category object shows `"books" = ();`. The model is just that, two entities related. Relation properties are optional, NOT transient and nullify on delete.

Comment: What happens with `NSLog(@"Category: %@", book.category)`? Also, adding an image of your model will help so I can see if the relationship is configured correctly.

Comment: Book.category shows the category. I will post the model later, as I have to anonimize it. I should add that if I set the inverse relation manually, everything works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can call

```
[context processPendingChanges];
```

to force the managed object context to update the inverse relationships immediately.

This method is automatically called during the event loop, or when you save the
context. But you can call it explicitly as well. From the documentation:

> Forces the receiver to process changes to the object graph.
>   ...
>   You can also invoke it manually to coalesce any pending unprocessed
>   changes.

Comment: I have not had much success with `-processPendingChanges` and inverse relationships.  I have always ended up letting the runloop finish.

Comment: Neat. It should work according to the documentation, but it doesn't for me. I suspect there might be something wrong with my model or project.

Comment: @hpique: I have tried your code and the inverse relationship `category.books` was set immediately. On the other hand, I could not name the entity "Category" because that name is already used in some runtime header.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't include the prefix to simplify. I think there's something else at play here. I will start removing code until I find it. Thanks for your help.